# Best way to manage set config variables in gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can any one tell me the best practice for initializing config variables and read that variables in gems?

Have tried with the following steps:
 This code is written in gem

```
config = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")
 @key = config["config"]["key"]
 server = config["config"]["server"]
```

and created yml file in config/config.yml in rails application.

Thanks in advance,

Jagdish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it once like following:

```
module YourGem
  class YourClass

    @config = { :username => "foo", :password => "bar" } # or @config = SomeHelperClass.default_config if the config is more complex
    @valid_config_keys = @config.keys

    # Configure through hash
    def self.configure(opts = {})
      opts.each { |k,v| @config[k.to_sym] = v if @valid_config_keys.include? k.to_sym }
    end

    # Configure through yaml file
    def self.configure_with(path_to_yaml_file)
      begin
        config = YAML::load(IO.read(path_to_yaml_file))
      rescue => e
        raise "YAML configuration file couldn't be found: #{e}"
      end
      configure(config)
    end

  end

end
```

And in your Rails Application, where you require your gem, you can add an initializer and configure like following:

config/initializers/your_initializer.rb

```
YourGem::YourClass.configure_with(path_to_the_yml_config_file)
```

This solution provides a default config, and the possibility to add a own yaml file to change the default values.

Comment: Thanks alot Mattherick.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my favourite way to set config variables in rails is using the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). Figaro basically makes use of the `ENV['x']` method that is available throughout rails. It stores all your config variables inside a common application.yml file and makes all the constants accessible via the ENV variable.

The bonus is that this translates 1 to 1 with the way Heroku does things as well.